# HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR when Querying S3 Inventory With Athena - Is size column correct?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I'm attempting to do some analysis on one of our S3 buckets using Athena and I'm getting some errors that I can't explain or find solutions for anywhere I look.

The guide I'm following is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory-athena-query.html.

I created my S3 inventory yesterday and have now received the first report in S3. The format is `Apache ORC`, the last export shows as yesterday and the additional fields stored are `Size`, `Last modified`, `Storage class`, `Encryption`.

I can see the data stored under `s3://{my-inventory-bucket}/{my-bucket}/{my-inventory}` so I know there is data there.

The default encryption on the inventory bucket and inventory configuration both have `SSE-S3` encryption enabled.

To create the table, I am using the following query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
  `bucket` string,
  key string,
  version_id string,
  is_latest boolean,
  is_delete_marker boolean,
  size bigint
)
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.SymlinkTextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://{my-inventory-bucket}/{my-bucket}/{my-inventory}/hive/';
```

Once the table has been created, I load the data using:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE my_table;
```

The results from loading the data show that data has been loaded:

```
Partitions not in metastore:    my_table=2021-07-17-00-00
Repair: Added partition to metastore my_table=2021-07-17-00-00
```

Once that's loaded, I verify the data is available using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT dt FROM my_table ORDER BY 1 DESC limit 10;
```

Which outputs:

```
1   2021-07-17-00-00
```

Now if I run something like the below, everything runs fine and I get the expected results:

```
SELECT key FROM my_table ORDER BY 1 DESC limit 10;
```

But as soon as I include the size column, I receive an error:

```
SELECT key, size FROM my_table ORDER BY 1 DESC limit 10;

Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Failed to read ORC file: s3://{my-inventory-bucket}/{my-bucket}/{my-inventory}/data/{UUID}.orc

This query ran against the "my_table" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum or contact customer support with Query Id: {UUID}.
```

I feel like I've got something wrong with my size column. Can anyone help figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So frustrating. Think I found the answer here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html

```
IsLatest – Set to True if the object is the current version of the object. (This field is not included if the list is only for the current version of objects.)
```

Removing that column fixed the problem.

Comment: For others benefit, I also had to remove the `is_delete_marker`, `version_id`, and `checksum_algorithm` columns. It seemed to work without removing `checksum_algorithm` but that column isn't present in my ORC files so 